# Delete DrRacket session history

Tags: racket

I'm using Mac OSX, and how can I delete my input history of DrRacket? 
I didn't find something like `.Racket_History` or these type of files in my folder 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

On Mac OS X, preferences are stored in `~/Library/Preferences` [*]. In my preferences, I have three files in this directory associated with Racket & DrRacket:

- org.racket-lang.DrRacket.plist
- org.racket-lang.Slideshow.plist
- org.racket-lang.prefs.rktd

You're unlikely to have the Slideshow prefs, but the others will likely be present. You can delete these to reset your preferences. Or, as you mentioned, you can use the menu entry!

[*] In case this isn't already clear, `~` refers to your home directory. Apologies if you already knew that.